# Micro Cloud Foundry offline mode

Tags: cloud-foundry

during the last week I spent all my time trying to access the MCF in offline mode. I'm working behind a company network (proxy) and the MCF try to do things that conflict with the local network.

I've followed several different tutorials such as [1. Working offline with MCF](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/infrastructure/micro/using-mcf.html#working-offline-with-micro-cloud-foundry) and [2. Working offline with MCF](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2011/09/08/working-offline-with-micro-cloud-foundry/). But the result keeps the same, even if I change all sort of configuration on my ubuntu.

**Trying to set up the target.**

vm target http: //api.mycloud.me

HTTP exception: Errno::ECONNREFUSED:Connection refused - connect(2)

**The MCF console show the following information:**

Identity:  mycloud.me (ok)

Admin:     admin@mycloud.me

IP address 10.0.x.x (network up / offline)

**When I ping to the IP address, I got positive return.**

PING 10.0.x.x (10.0.x.x) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 10.0.x.x: icmp_req=1 ttl=62 time=1.06 ms

64 bytes from 10.0.x.x: icmp_req=2 ttl=62 time=0.896 ms

64 bytes from 10.0.x.x: icmp_req=3 ttl=62 time=0.880 ms

--- 10.0.2.15 ping statistics ---

3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.880/0.948/1.069/0.089 ms

But if I try to do a telnet to the port 80 or a ssh I got connection refused error.

**ssh: connect to host mycloud.me port 22: Connection refused**

I don't know what I need to do to fix this, if anyone have a tip that help me to figure out a solution, I'll be very thankful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

OK dudes! That I fixed it!

So, after some problems to understand what was happening, I could finally connect to the Micro Cloud. I'm still validating the information from the two tutorials above, because could have some conflicted data.

I didn't test if it is necessary to set a nameserver to the dhclient, but the second tutorial seems to be more reliable. Just one tip, run the ssh -L tunnel on a separate terminal, and leave it open. This wasn't so clear for people like me, that was not used to working with network administration.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

given the assigned IP address, it looks like you are using bridged networking, have you tried changing the VM configuration to use NAT instead?

This will use an interface exclusive to your local machine and the VM and shouldn't be affected by your corporate network.

Comment: Hi Dan, I'm using NAT, actually the VM comes with this configuration by default. However, by a strange motive, I can sign in with vcap user to the console pressing Alt+F2 and access my host with ssh. But not access the guest from the host. I still looking for a solution for this connection refuse problem.

Comment: I was trying to use Virtual Box, but for some reason, the NAT is getting a IP from the network. So I patched the VMWare Player and I could access the MCF by ssh, but still getting connection refuse when I tried to change my vmc target to http://api.vcap.me (default address).